# Message queue vs thread lock

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, message-queue

I have a windows application build on .net technology. In my application I get lots of messages from different threads. Once I get a message I need to call a function which should be thread safe. 
I have used

```
lock (lockThis)
        {
            TSFunction(message);
        }
```

Now some one recommended me to use message queue instead. I am not at all familiar with this approach but I want to choose the better one.
Should I switch to message queue? If yes then can someone please point me to some good tutorial?

Comment: Calling your function inside a `lock` does not make the function thread safe. Nor does a message queue make anything intrinsically thread safe. The only thing that can be reliably made thread safe is the *content* of the method, not the way you call it. Either way, asking StackOverflow whether you should switch assumes far too much knowledge of your system on our behalf (we have no idea what your wider requirements are!) and is also a fairly subjective question in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

With your current design, whenever you are processing a message, the other threads are completely blocked. If it's not a problem, then who cares, right?

If this bothers you (for example, you want to improve the responsiveness), then yes, a message queue would be a good idea. You need to assume the lock, put the message in the queue, and then release the lock (or find a thread-safe collection that does it for you). Then you deal with the message later. This way, the message sending threads will be blocked for a negligible amount of time only.

Be warned though: message processing will be unsynchronized. So for example, if the message processing is slow, then it is possible for a thread to send multiple messages before they get processed. It is for you to decide if you can allow this. This actually makes your application less thread-safe, while it could perform better (less wait times).

You can even do the message processing in a thread pool, process multiple messages in parallel, etc. The options are endless.

Comment: Depends on the locking patterns in those other threads.